# Find closing bracket in bash

Tags: bash

I have a terraform script that looks like this

```
pipeline_schedules = [{ <== ( I know this line number through a grep command )
  description = "pipeline1"
  ref         = "5.2.0"
  cron        = ""
  variables   = []
  }, {
  description = "pipeline2"
  ref         = "5.2.1"
  cron        = ""
  variables   = []
}] # <== ( I want to find this line number )
```

Through a bash script, I want to find the line number of the end of the array of `pipeline_schedules`, assuming I know the the line number where the array starts. If it wasn't for the existence of other arrays ( `variables = []` ) inside the array, it would have been simple.

Any help please ?

Comment: I don't know Terraform, but does it have a parser you could use? That'd be better. I imagine it's possible for those strings to contain arbitrary data, like closing brackets, which means regex would choke. Actually, why do you need the line number in the first place? This could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Like, if you're ultimately trying to extract the definition of `pipeline_schedules`, you could just use the parser and not have to worry about line numbers.

Comment: In general, this is a place to use a real parser, not a shell script using syntax-unaware tools. In particular, there is tooling available for round-tripping Terraform syntax to and from JSON. Use those, and you can query or edit your tf code with tools like `jq`, and you can interact with your tf code on a semantic/conceptual level instead of as text.

Comment: What do you need the line number for?

Comment: @wjandrea, this is a bash question actually, not terraform...

Comment: @Jeter-work What do you mean? OP's talking about parsing a Terraform script.

Answer (score 1):

Context would be great! What are you actually trying to do with those line numbers?

You found the line number of the opening brackets with grep, you can find the closing brackets with grep too:

```
grep -n '^}]'
```

Answer (score -1):

- Use regular expressions, including \n* for endlines.
- If you're trying to extract information, use lookahead and capture
  groups.  Also consider using `sed`.
- If you're trying to modify the resource file, regex, lookahead,
  capture groups and sed are your answer again.

Comment: Based on OP's example, Terraform isn't a regular language, so regex isn't a good tool for the job. That's why I recommended using an actual parser in my comment.